# MATLAB: How to optimize multiple calls to oligoprop

Tags: arrays, matlab, optimization, bioinformatics, cell-array

**A short bit of background:**

I am working on designing a molecular probe for In Situ Hybridization to be able to study the expression of particular genes in various tissues.
In order to do that I need to find a sequence in that gene that best fits certain criteria.
The sequence is analysed using the function **oligoprop** from the *Bioinformatics Toolbox* in Matlab.

**The problem:**

The program takes some time, and I would like to optimize it. I have used the Matlab Profiler and identified this line of code as one of the most time consuming.

```
oligopropsOfSequences = arrayfun(@(x) oligoprop(char(x), ...
                                            'Dimerlength', 3, ...
                                            'HPBase', 3), ...
                                            sequences);
```

> **sequences** are a 1byX cell array. It is usually around 3000 element long.
>
> **oligoprop** is the function from the Bioinformatics Toolbox
>
> The arguments to the **oligoprop** Dimerlength and HPBase are required for my analysis

I have done the same "operation" in a for loop already and the overall performance was only slightly increased by the use of arrayfun. So far it also seems as if the *oligoprop* itself, simply takes time, which is understandable.

I also have to admit that I am a native Python programmer new to Matlab, so I am not yet well versed in which structures to use and in general how Matlab does things. So any kind of supporting information is welcome.

> To test it here is an example short sequences cell array

```
sequences = {'caccagtggatgctagccgccctgctggccccggggatggacgtc', 'accagtggatgctagccgccctgctggccccggggatggacgtcc', 'ccagtggatgctagccgccctgctggccccggggatggacgtcca', 'cagtggatgctagccgccctgctggccccggggatggacgtccaa', 'agtggatgctagccgccctgctggccccggggatggacgtccaaa'}
```

> EDIT 1:

As suggested, I tried to use the `cellfun`, at first I got some errors, but was able to get rid of them, only to encounter a semantic problem.
Code as follows:

```
oligopropsOfSequences = cellfun(@(x) oligoprop(x, ...
                                            'Dimerlength', 3, ...
                                            'HPBase', 3), ...
                                            sequences, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

The code does not produce any errors, but what I get is a 1byX cell array, containing my structs, instead of getting a Xby1 structure array.
I don't know how to convert that cell array back into the structure array, plus I am worried that the operation itself might be costly.

And since my later operations depend on the structure array, I cannot really profile the whole function properly to see if there are any speed gains.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but that `char(x)` caused by using `arrayfun` instead of `cellfun` looks suspicious. Have you timed it using `cellfun`? How were you accessing the cell elements in the loop? If you're doing `char(sequences(k))` then `sequences{k}` with curly brackets might help a tiny bit. (Either that or put them in a normal array if all of the sequence lengths are the same.) Also, as these calls are apparently independent, using a `parfor` loop might better utilize multiple cores.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Tried it, it was slower. 
I still have to try the `cellfun`, I am having some trouble with it.
That char seems wrong to me as well. but when I remove it I get errors and am unsure how to fix them.

Comment: Which one was slower? Can you edit your question and add the code and the error you get when you try `cellfun`?

Comment: I put the edit about the `cellfun` in.
The "slower" refereed to using the `parfor` loop. But thanks for mentioning it, I was not aware of its existence, it might come handy at some other occasion.